# Handling a timer from a class

Tags: vb.net, timer

I want some values in a class to decrease whenever the timer in the main form ticks. I am creating multiple instances of the same class as my program is a simulation application and I am not storing these instances in an array or any list in that matter. I simply declare them and add their picture box to the controls on the main form. However I am hoping to have a sub routine inside the class that triggers whenever the timer in the main form ticks. I thought of something like this:

```
Public Class Jimmy
    Dim _a As Integer = 10

    Sub decreseNum(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles mainapp.tmrLog.Tick
        _a -= 1
    End Sub

End Class
```

with `mainapp` being the name of the main form and `tmrLog` being the timer I want to associate my sub routine with. However the above code doesn't work

Comment: The sub wont work because you do not call it. If you want the sub to start work as soon as your create a new instance, you should do this using a [constructor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructor_(object-oriented_programming)).

Comment: I'd suggest putting them into a collection of some sort, then have the timer call the Decrement method on each object using a For Each loop

Comment: To expand on my previous comment, the reason I would do it this way is that the coupling is looser between the timer and the objects. eg the decrement method can be easily called from elsewhere. If you have a ref to the timer within the object, then the main and the objects know too much about each other.

Comment: I have a constructor in this class, I just didn't bother to include. Anyway I found an answer to this question. I used "AddHandler tmrLog.Tick, AddressOf decreaseNum" and it works now

Answer (score 0):

You could try defining a local reference to the timer in the Jimmy class:

```
Public Class Jimmy
    Dim _a As Integer = 10
    Private WithEvents tmr As Timer

    Public Sub New(ByRef MainTmr As Timer)
        tmr = MainTmr
    End Sub

    Sub decreseNum(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tmr.Tick
        _a -= 1
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want all your classes react to `timer.elapsed` event, just sign up for it. The program below is fully operational. It is example what you can do to have your children to react to timer events of single parent/timer

```
Imports System
imports system.timers

Public Module Module1
    Public Sub Main()

        dim mc as new MainClass()
        mc.CreateChildren(5)
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(60000) ' wait and monitor output of childern
        mc.Stop()
        Console.WriteLine("All should stop now...")
        Console.Read()
    End Sub
End Module

public class MainClass 'This class could be your form

    private _timer as new Timer(5000)

    public sub  CreateChildren(count as integer)

        For i as integer = 1 to count
            dim c as new Child(i)
            Addhandler _timer.Elapsed, addressof c.DoWhentimerTicks
        next
        Console.WriteLine("timer should run now...")
        _timer.Start()

    end sub

    public sub [Stop]()
       _timer.Stop()
    End Sub

End class


public class Child

    private _myNO as integer

    public sub new (no as integer)
        _myNo = no
    end sub

    public sub  DoWhentimerTicks(sender as object , e as ElapsedEventArgs)


    Console.WriteLine(string.format("Child #{0} just ticked. Time = {1}", _myNo, e.signaltime))

    end sub
End class
```

Answer (score -1):

I found my solution, posting here for further reference.
My situation was trying to have my timer in the mainform triggering a sub in a class, and I used the following solution.

Class:

```
Sub addHandlesToSub
    AddHandler Form1.Timer1.Tick, AddressOf subToBeTriggered
End Sub

Sub subToBeTriggered(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    'My code
End Sub
```

The parameters in subToBeTriggered are useful when you want to remove the handler with

```
RemoveHandler Form1.Timer1.Tick, AddressOf subToBeTriggered
```

Otherwise, there will be an error without the parameters.

Thanks for all the answers though.

Comment: It is nice that you posing your own answer as solution but I already gave you complete answer how to do what you want to do, and it included AddHandler. Have you actually looked at the slick patterned solution I provided?